# jQuery TabData: Is it possible to get the ClickedTab data, instead index?

Tags: jquery, tabs, click

I have designing the TabMenu Like following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('#container-1').tabs();
      $('#container-2').tabs();
    }
</script>

.....
<div id="container-1">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span id="start">First</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="container-2">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span id="end">Last</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
.....
```

Is it possible to get the ClickedTab data, instead of the index? Like if ClickTab is first then `#fragment1`. Else if ClickTab is last, `#fragment2`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify what you mean?

If you change this:

```
<li><a href="#fragment-1"><span id="end">Last</span></a></li>
```

to:

```
<li><a href="#fragment-2"><span id="end">Last</span></a></li>
```

Then it will load #fragment-2 when you click it.

If you actually want to get the data of the clicked tab, then you can hook into the tabsselect event

```
$('.ui-tabs-nav').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
//ui.panel is a dom element that contains the contents of the clicked tab.
}
```

Further reading available at the [Jquery UI docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this means you got the other part working.  Building on the previous example this is possible:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#container-1').tabs({
          selected : function(e, ui) {
            if ($($("a", e.target).get(ui.index)).attr('href') == '#fragment-1') {
                alert('First clicked!');
            }
          }        
      }); 
  });
   ....
  <div  id="container-1">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Contact</span></a></li>

         </ul>
  </div>
```

Ultimately it is probably better to use index since this requires you to know a bit of the tab implementation details and you can use a switch to handle the logic for each tab.  However, if you feel that the content suits your needs better, than this should work just fine.